# how to add gerrit-trigger events inside Jenkins pipeline code, inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gerrit-trigger

I would like to add gerrit trigger events inside Jenkinsfile, like we have in JobDSL,

```
        triggers {
            upstream('pipeline_properties', 'UNSTABLE')
            gerrit {
                events {
                    refUpdated()
                }
                project('reg_exp:jenkins', ["plain:${jenkins_branch}"])
            }
        }
```

Is this something possible in pipeline code, could able to find some things like cron and stuffs under triggers but not able to get a reference how to add the gerrit-trigger event inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one working `Jenkinsfile` covers the gerrit trigger event part, see reference below the code segment

`BuildDiscarderProperty` & `SCMTrigger` are used for sample as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy          
properties(
    [
        [
            $class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty',
            strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', numToKeepStr: '10']
        ],
        pipelineTriggers([
            [
                $class: 'SCMTrigger',
                scmpoll_spec: "H H 1,15 1-11 *"
            ],
            [
                $class: 'GerritTrigger', gerritProjects: [
                    [
                        $class: "GerritProject", 
                        compareType: "REG_EXP",
                        pattern: "jenkins",
                        branches: [
                            [
                                $class: "Branch",
                                pattern: "\${jenkins_branch}"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                triggerOnEvents: [
                    [$class: "PluginRefUpdatedEvent"]
                ]
            ]
        ])
    ]
)
node {
    echo 'Hello World'
}
```

Useful reference

- [gerrit trigger source code@github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/hudson/plugins/gerrit/trigger/hudsontrigger)
- Hints for pipelineTriggers https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37731

`config.xml` under `JENKINS_HOME` job directory is used for debug

Comment: This works for a scripted pipeline, but what about a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a **declarative pipeline** (in contrast to a scripted pipeline, for which the properties approach used in the other answers should work), you want to use the 'triggers' directive.  Confusingly, using `properties` seems to work, but ends up (silently) clashing with other declarative things such as `options` and `triggers`.

The best way to painlessly generate the Gerrit triggers declarative directives is to use the Jenkins generator, available for any Jenkins instance at `https://$your-jenkins-host/directive-generator`.

### Example

1. Navigate to `https://$your-jenkins-host/directive-generator`
2. Select "triggers: Triggers" as the Sample Directive field.
3. Add triggers, for example to trigger when a patchset is created or when a "!build" comment is posted.
4. Add a project with a pattern matching its name and another one matching one or more branches.
5. Click the "Generate Declarative Directive" button.

You should get something like:

```
triggers {
  gerrit customUrl: '', gerritProjects: [[branches: [[compareType: 'PLAIN', pattern: 'master']], compareType: 'PLAIN', disableStrictForbiddenFileVerification: false, pattern: 'ring-project']], triggerOnEvents: [commentAddedContains('!build'), patchsetCreated(excludeDrafts: true, excludeNoCodeChange: true, excludeTrivialRebase: true)]
}
```

Ready to be used in your declarative pipeline Jenkinsfile.

---